# Is there a way to schedule changes to a page?

Tags: pages, scheduled-posts

Our clients would like to schedule changes made to a given **page** (for instance by displaying the link to register to an event).

Typically, the same page (/registration) should display (before the registration opening):
"The registrations will be open by ..."

Once the time comes, the same page should display:
"Registrer by clicking on this link..."

I tried to follow the below procedure, but it doesn't help:
https://en.support.wordpress.com/schedule-a-page/

Is there a way to have 2 versions (or revision - one published and one as draft) where the draft version would become published automatically?

Or a way to have two different pages sharing the same url (one being published until a given date and the other one getting published right after the first gets unpublished)?

Preferably, this procedure should not involve a developer every time a bit of text is changed on a page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a shortcode like this

```
add_shortcode("custom_text_se282078", function ($attr, $content, $tag) {

    $result = "";

    if (date_i18n("H") > $attr["time"]) {
        $result = $attr["text_after"];
    } else {
        $result = $attr["text_before"];
    }

    return $result;

});
```

with that you just have to put that in the page :

[custom_text_se282078 time="10" text_before="text before 10 h" text_after="texte after 10 h"]

Comment: it actually does the trick, but requires a developer to code and deploy the new short code, which is not "user friendly"

Comment: you don't explain what is "user friendly" in your inital question. can you give more details ?

Comment: you are right, I'll edit de question. I meant without having to involve a developer every time we need to change a piece of text in the page.

Comment: Make it `[display_between_time start="2017-10-09 15:00:00" start="2017-10-09 16:00:00"]Register now![/display_between_time]` and check those dates against the current time to give full control to users. Just have multiple of those if you want to hide some and show other content.

Comment: I edit my answer, you can use parameters in the shortcode. in this parameters you can put links, post ID or other data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mmm answer, my code look like this:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'start' => ''
), $attributes));

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'end' => ''
), $attributes));

if (($start_timestamp = strtotime($start)) === false) {
    $error = new WP_Error('unable to parse', 'Unable to parse start timestamp', $start);
    scheduler_log($error);
    return '';
}

if (($end_timestamp = strtotime($end)) === false) {
    $error = new WP_Error('unable to parse', 'Unable to parse end timestamp', $end);
    scheduler_log($error);
    return '';
}

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Zurich");
$now = strtotime("now");

if($now>=$start_timestamp && $now<=$end_timestamp){
    return $content;
}
else{
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-shortcode based solution, the free Revisionary Plugin offers this functionality: https://wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/

One important note: The plugin hasn't been updated in several years. I have used it in the past and it has worked well in the past. However, I don't know if it is still under active development.